# Alamofire a general retry pattern - when http times out

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have the following solution for retrying - fetching data using Alamofire. That is when the server is to slow to serve, within a specified number of seconds.

This is working allright, but I would like to make this more clean - as I have many endpoints. Can you see how I can improve this, like moving code to the base class - but then how to re-call the same superclass endpoint from the base class.

Any improvements are welcome - thanks

The endpoint(slow and will timeout) class

```
import Foundation
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire

public class EndpointSlow: BaseEndpoint {

    public override init(){

    }

    public func getSlow(completionClosure: @escaping (_ items: EndpointEntity?) -> () ) {

        let url = self._url + "/slow/file.json"

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        Singleton.sharedInstance.pdAlamofire.request(
            url,
            method: .get,
            headers: headers).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<EndpointEntity>) in

                let obj = response.result.value

                switch (response.result) {
                case .success:
                    print("Slow... done")
                    self.resetRetry()
                    completionClosure(obj)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                        print("Timeout...")

                        if self.shouldRetry(){
                            self.getSlow(completionClosure: { (endpointEntity: EndpointEntity?) in
                                completionClosure(endpointEntity)
                            })
                        }else{
                            print("Error handeling...")
                        }

                    }
                    print("\n\nAuth request failed with error:\n \(error)")
                    break
                }


        }

    }

}
```

Endpoint base class:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public class BaseEndpoint{
    let _url = "http://localhost:8080"

    let retry = Singleton.sharedInstance.retryCount
    var retryCount: Int = 0


    public func showReloadingAnimation(){

    }

    public func hideReloadingAnimation(){


    }

    public func resetRetry() {

        self.hideReloadingAnimation()
        self.retryCount = 0

    }

    public func shouldRetry() -> Bool {
        if (self.retryCount <= self.retry){
            self.retryCount = self.retryCount+1
            return true
        }else{
            self.retryCount = 0
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Finally I have a Singleton, where I setup Alamofire SessionManager:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public class Singleton {

    var pdAlamofire : Alamofire.SessionManager
    var retryCount = 3
    public static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    init() {

        // Alamofire setup
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 1 // seconds for testing

        self.pdAlamofire = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

        // Chaching
        URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: why have another class that inherits from BaseEndPoint? Why not just abstract the retry logic completely and place everything into BaseEndPoint? Also, are you retrying that request as soon as it fails?

Comment: Thanks. When ever I get a timeout, then I try again. I tried something like that with the retry logic, but I ended up wanting to be able to call the super class's endpoint - and the the signature of the function changes, depending on the endpoint.

Comment: For retry logic in apps I would definitely recommend waiting between requests(whether that be running a background thread and having it wait, or having it run on app enters foreground, etc). since apps in general are very unstable in the sense that they aren't always reliably connected to the web. Or use a library that waits to see until internet is available and then run your request. There's many ways for retry logic but I definitely recommend not having it just constantly trying to send it.

Comment: Thanks. I will only try x times, defined in a constant.